# In "A Boy and His Blob" for the Nintendo Wii, is there any reason to rescue the blobs in world 4?

Tags: nintendo-wii, a-boy-and-his-blob

In "A Boy and His Blob" for the Nintendo Wii, I have gotten to the fourth world, but have not yet beaten the game... so please don't tell me the ending :-) I have been trying to rescue all the blobs in the hanging cages that I can, but every time I die, the blobs are back in the cages... does rescuing the blobs have any significant effect? And if so, should I go back and replay the levels trying not to die and saving all the blobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've beaten the game three times now and have seen no effect to saving or not saving the blobs.